# IONIC TABS disable horizontal slide

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic Slide box and I want to disable for a user to slide between content horizontally using $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(false);
but this means i cant scroll vertically with the content. How do I work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ion-content scroll == true inside ion-slide

```html
<ion-slide-box show-pager="false"   on-slide-changed="yourfunction()" does-continue="false" auto-play="false" slide-interval="100" >

 <ion-slide>
<ion-content scroll="true">
  your first slide
</ion-content>
 </ion-slide>

<ion-slide>
 <ion-content scroll="true">
  your second slide
</ion-content>
 </ion-slide>

<ion-slide>
<ion-content scroll="true">
  your third slide
</ion-content>
</ion-slide>

 </ion-slide-box>
```